# Finding coefficients of $x^n$ and $x^{n+r}$ in an expansion

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I have to find the coefficients of $x^n$ and $x^{n+r}$ $(1 < r < n)$ in the expansion of:

$$(1 + x)^{2n} + x(1 + x)^{2n - 1} + x^2(1 + x)^{2n - 2} + ... + x^n(1 + x)^n$$

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ S = (1 + x)^{2n} + x(1 + x)^{2n - 1} + x^2(1 + x)^{2n - 2} + ... + x^n(1 + x)^n.........................(1)$$

Now Multiply both side by $\displaystyle \frac{x}{(1+x)}\;,$ We get

$$\displaystyle S\frac{x}{(1+x)} = x\cdot (1+x)^{2n-1}+x^2\cdot (1+x)^{2n-2}+.......+x^{n+1}\cdot (1+x)^{n-1}...............(2)$$

So $$\displaystyle S\left[1-\frac{x}{1+x}\right] = (1+x)^{2n} - x^{n+1}(1+x)^{n-1}$$

So We get $$\displaystyle S = (1+x)\cdot \left[(1+x)^{2n}-x^{n+1}\cdot (1+x)^{n-1}\right]$$

$\bullet \; \; $Now find Coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $$\displaystyle (1+x)^{2n+1}-x^{n+1}\cdot (1+x)^n$$

So Coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $(1+x)^{2n+1}-$ coeff.  of $x^{n}$ in $\displaystyle x^{n+1}\cdot (1+x)^n $

So Coeff. of $\displaystyle x^{n} = \binom{2n+1}{n}.$

$\bullet\;\; $ Now Coeff. of $x^{n+r}$ in $(1+x)^{2n+1}-$ coeff.  of $x^{n+r}$ in $\displaystyle x^{n+1}\cdot (1+x)^n $

So Coeff. of $\displaystyle x^{n+r} = \binom{2n+1}{n+r}-\left[\binom{n}{r-1}\right]$

For Calculation of Coeff. of $\displaystyle x^{n+r}$ in $x^{n+1}\cdot (1+x)^n = \displaystyle \frac{(x+x^2)^n}{x}$

We have used the following process.

So Coeff. of $x^{n+r-1}$ in $(x+x^2)^{n}$

Let we assume that Coeff. of $x^{n+r-1}$ occur in $\bf{T_{s+1}}^{th}$ term

So $\bf{T_{s+1}}^{th}$ term in $$\displaystyle (x+x^2)^n = \binom{n}{s}\cdot x^{n-s}\cdot (x)^{2s} = \binom{n}{s}\cdot x^{n+s}$$

Here $$x^{n+s} = x^{n+r-1}\Rightarrow n+s = n+r-1\Rightarrow s=r-1$$

So Coeff. of $x^{n+r-1}$ in $$\displaystyle (x+x^2)^{n} = \binom{n}{s} = \binom{n}{r-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{r=0}^n(1+x)^{2n-r}x^r=(1+x)^{2n}\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\dfrac x{1+x}\right)^r$$

$$=(1+x)^{2n}\dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac x{1+x}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\dfrac x{1+x}}$$

$$=(1+x)^{2n+1}-x^{n+1}(1+x)^n$$

Now the coefficient of $x^m,n+1\le m\le 2n+1$

$$=\binom{2n+1}m-\binom n{m-(n+1)}$$